# how to check if I already set uncaughtException event

Tags: node.js

I use `process.on "uncaughtException"`. And sometimes I call it several times because of not trivial module system. So I got warning:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

My code:

```
var onError = function (){
    if (true) // how to check if I allready set uncaughtException event?
    {
        process.on ("uncaughtException", function  (err) {
            console.log ("uncaughtException");
            throw err;
            } 
        );
    }
};
```

For simulating several calls I use cycle:

```
var n = 12;
for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    onError();
};
```

So how to check if I allready set `uncaughtException` event?

Comment: Why do you bind multiple uncaughtException listeners? Just bind it once on the beginning of your app.js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `process` is an `EventEmitter` ([docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html)), you can use `process.listeners('uncaughtException')` to retrieve an array of listeners already attached (and therefore `.length` to see how many you have bound).

You can also use `process.removeAllListeners('uncaughtException')` to remove already-bound listeners if you wanted ([docs](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_event)).

```
var onError = function (){
    if (process.listeners('uncaughtException').length == 0) // how to check if I allready set uncaughtException event?
    {
        process.on ("uncaughtException", function  (err) {
            console.log ("uncaughtException");
            throw err;
            } 
        );
    }
};
```

Note also that what you're seeing is just a *warning*; there's no *problem* with adding as many listeners as you have done.

Comment: Yes, it is a warning but if you bind the same listener multiple times wouldn't it be called multiple times on the event?

Comment: @SnowBlind: Yes, it will fire multiple times.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants to happen. Just a heads up.

Comment: @SnowBlind: Humm. Hopefully the OP can clarify as necessary :).